# Trying to create maven dynamic web project in eclipse with java and clojure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, clojure

I have created maven-archetype-webapp project in Eclipse. And I want to use Clojure code in Java.
So, there is my core.clj file:

```
(ns coq.core
 (:gen-class
   :name coq.core
    :methods [#^{:static true} [foo [int] void]]))

(defn -foo [i] (println "Hello from Clojure. My input was " i))

(defn -main [] (println "Hello from Clojure -main." ))
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>gleboGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>javaandclojure</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>javaandclojure Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1-b02</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>javaandclojure</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectories>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
                </sourceDirectories>
                <testSourceDirectories>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</testSourceDirectory>
                </testSourceDirectories>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

There is my single servlet with error on core.foo(123):

```
package com.javaandclojure;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import coq.*;

@WebServlet({ "/*"})
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("inside get!");
        core.foo(123);// core cannot be resolved
        request.setAttribute("number", 42);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Some scrinshots from eclipse:

[image]

build path:

[image]

Maven Build with goals:" clean package" gives it:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building javaandclojure Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ javaandclojure ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\porn\indigo\javaandclojure\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ javaandclojure ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ javaandclojure ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\porn\indigo\javaandclojure\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \porn\indigo\javaandclojure\src\main\java\com\javaandclojure\Main.java:[10,10] error: package coq does not exist
[ERROR] \porn\indigo\javaandclojure\src\main\java\com\javaandclojure\Main.java:[17,2] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.042s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 11 16:28:25 EET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project javaandclojure: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \porn\indigo\javaandclojure\src\main\java\com\javaandclojure\Main.java:[10,10] error: package coq does not exist
[ERROR] \porn\indigo\javaandclojure\src\main\java\com\javaandclojure\Main.java:[17,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Maybe I should have used another maven archetype?

Comment: Have you looked at the .class files clojure generates?

Comment: javaandclojure\target\javaandclojure\WEB-INF\classes\coq\ contains: core$_foo.class, core$_main, core$loading__4505__auto__.class, core.class, core__init.class, core.cls

Answer (score 2):

That is because the Java compiler is being run before the clojure compiler.

If you force the Java compilation to take place after the `clojure-maven-plugin` it will work. Add these lines **after** the `clojure-maven-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have changed pom.xml and nothing have changed. Well I changed it?

Comment: If you run `mvn compile` from command line you'll see that it works. Without that plugin configuration I suggested it wouldn't compile.

Comment: after goals: "clean install package" still gets [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR

Comment: Add that log to your question. BTW it doesn't make sense to call `install package` since the `package` phase will be called when calling `install`. `mvn clean install` will do.

Comment: OK, I updated the plugin configuration a little bit. You'll have to disable the default compilation and then enable them with another id. Try with this conf. It really should work.

Comment: Now it's building well. But eclipse still shows the error in Main.class and when i triyed to access servlet I gets it: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.IFn

Comment: You're welcome. I must admit that I am no eclipse expert. I use another IDE so that part I cannot help you with.

Comment: Eclipse error is just half of problem. Main problem  corresponds to  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.IFn)))))

Comment: You will be a lot happier and a lot warmer if you just keep your clojure code in a separate project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a project with 2 modules so it is clear what depends on what. If your Java code has to depend on your Clojure code, then the java module (war?) should depend on the clojure module.